Pass a delegate into servicecollection c# web API
I am trying to pass a method into a library from my calling API project. The library needs to receive a pointer to the method in a non-static class that has other dependencies. The library calls the API method in a background process (has ran successfully prior to dynamically passing the method as a delegate).When the class library is shared between projects i dont want the calling API to have to implement the interfaces in the library but rather pass the method to it (possibly using delegate if that is best option
I get a null reference exception with the dependencies that are required in SummaryService (registered elsewhere as Scoped).
Trying to be brief as possible with some code excerpts, but there are a few dependencies and complications around dynamically specifying a method to run, using a background service and general confusion around scoping of lifetimes etc.
I have the following code using a Func expression to let my library know what method to use  - program.cs
MethodInfo method = typeof(SummaryService).GetMethod("Delete");
                Func<string, Task> deletionFunc = (Func<string, Task>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<string, Task>),null, method);
                builder.Services.AddServiceBusUserAccountDataDeletion("ServiceBusConsumerConfig", deletionFunc);

I have the following extension method in my class library.
public static IServiceCollection AddServiceBusUserAccountDataDeletion(
          this IServiceCollection services, string configSectionPath,Func<string, Task> deleteMethod)
        {
services.AddScoped<IDeletionService, DeletionService>(sp => new DeletionService(deleteMethod));
}

This is my deletion service in my library that should call SummaryService Delete method in my API project.
public class DeletionService : IDeletionService
{
    private readonly Func<string, Task> _callBack;

    public DeletionService(Func<string, Task> callBack)
    {
        _callBack = callBack;
    }
    public async Task Delete(string userId)
    {
        await _callBack(userId).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}

Is there anything obvious that I need to change/add or is there a better way to achieve this entirely?

You can try getting the proper instance of the SummaryService via the service provider when registering your DeletionService, like this:
services.AddScoped(sp => 
{
    var summaryService = sp.GetRequiredService<SummaryService>();
    return new DeletionService(summaryService.Delete));
});



The library needs to receive a pointer to the method in a non-static class
...
Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<string, Task>),null, method);
...
I get a null reference exception with the dependencies that are required in SummaryService (registered elsewhere as Scoped).

Since the method is not static, you would need to pass an instance in where you're currently passing null.
Since you presumably don't have access to the instance at this point, you'll need to change your extension method to allow the caller to resolve the instance.
public static IServiceCollection AddServiceBusUserAccountDataDeletion(
          this IServiceCollection services, 
          string configSectionPath,
          Func<IServiceProvider, Func<string, Task>> getDeleteMethod)
{
    services.AddScoped<IDeletionService, DeletionService>(sp => 
        new DeletionService(getDeleteMethod(sp)));
}

builder.Services.AddServiceBusUserAccountDataDeletion("ServiceBusConsumerConfig", sp => userId => sp.GetRequiredService<SummaryService>().Delete(userId));

As you can see, it gets a little awkward. It may be simpler to just have consumers implement your library's interface when they need to inject services. You're not reducing coupling by requiring a delegate instead of an interface: Just as closures are poor man's objects, a delegate is just a different way to represent an interface with one function.
Update
Based on your comments regarding scopes and disposed objects, you probably need to change how you use it to something like this:
builder.Services.AddServiceBusUserAccountDataDeletion(
    "ServiceBusConsumerConfig", 
    sp => {
        var summaryService = sp.GetRequiredService<SummaryService>();
        return userId => summaryService.Delete(userId));
    });

This ensures SummaryService is resolved at the time that the IDeletionService is resolved, while the service provider is in scope. Then that captured SummaryService instance gets used when the resulting callback is invoked--basically mimicking what would have happened if you'd used a class to inject SummaryService and a method instead of a callback. In other words, using a closure as a poor man's object.

This was the type of solution I wanted as it means my consumer can have a single line to implement it. It builds ok, but when the API runs it gives the following error System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'IServiceProvider'.

@user900566: That indicates that your deletion service is getting created after the service provider has been disposed. Why is this service Scoped? Do you expect to use it outside of a request scope? The fact that you're trying to pass a user string as a parameter to the factory makes me think this probably isn't the best pattern. Perhaps in a separate question you could share what you're actually trying to accomplish and ask for a suggested way to go about it?

It’s a servicebus background process being added to an existing API. The existing API already has a scoped service that it uses that has the delete method that accepts a userid. The topic in servicebus receives a message containing the userid and this gets processed by the background service in the API. Trying to use the existing scoped process in a background service which is singleton by default hence needs to create its own scope.

You seem to be having a scope out of lifetime problem.
You have to pass the IServiceProvider into your class and make a new scope to use the service.
This is a simple example that you can use to rework your code.
public class MySingletonService
{
private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
public MySingletonService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
}

public void DoWork()
{
    // Create a new scope to get a scoped service
    using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
    {
        var scopedService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyScopedService>();
        scopedService.DoSomething();
    }
}

